# Ошибка chromedriver при driver.get("url");

Tags: java, selenium, chrome-extension, selenium-webdriver

Запускаю программу и когда строчка до ходит `driver.get("url");`
открывается Google с ссылкой на data:, а потом 
Код:

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","chromedriver.exe");  
      WebDriver d = new ChromeDriver();
```

вылезает вот такая ошибка:

```
Exception in thread "Thread-1" org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException:   
java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
Build info: version: 'unknown', revision: '1969d75', time: '2016-10-18  
09:43:45 -0700'
System info: host: 'home-pc', ip: '169.254.7.242', os.name: 'Windows 10',  
os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_65'
Driver info: driver.version: RemoteWebDriver
at    
org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:91)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:601)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.get(RemoteWebDriver.java:322)
at авторизация.login(авторизация.java:37)
at авторизация.run(авторизация.java:27)
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.http.impl.io.SessionInputBufferImpl.streamRead(SessionInputBufferImpl.java:139)
at org.apache.http.impl.io.SessionInputBufferImpl.fillBuffer(SessionInputBufferImpl.java:155)
at org.apache.http.impl.io.SessionInputBufferImpl.readLine(SessionInputBufferImpl.java:284)
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpResponseParser.parseHead(DefaultHttpResponseParser.java:140)
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpResponseParser.parseHead(DefaultHttpResponseParser.java:57)
at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractMessageParser.parse(AbstractMessageParser.java:261)
at org.apache.http.impl.DefaultBHttpClientConnection.receiveResponseHeader(DefaultBHttpClientConnection.java:165)
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.CPoolProxy.receiveResponseHeader(CPoolProxy.java:167)
at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.doReceiveResponse(HttpRequestExecutor.java:272)
at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.execute(HttpRequestExecutor.java:124)
at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:271)
at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:184)
at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec.execute(RetryExec.java:88)
at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RedirectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:110)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:184)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:71)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:55)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.internal.ApacheHttpClient.fallBackExecute(ApacheHttpClient.java:142)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.internal.ApacheHttpClient.execute(ApacheHttpClient.java:88)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:160)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:82)
... 4 more
```

Comment: И вы так думаете, что глядя только на эту ошибку вам скажут, что не так с этой строчкой? Приведите полный фрагмент кода, минимально необходимый для воспроизведения проблемы, а не одну эту строку. Без этого вопрос стоит закрыть.

Comment: покажите как вы инициализируете `driver`

Comment: @tCode                          System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "chromedriver.exe");
 d = new ChromeDriver();

Comment: @Ак                                                System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "chromedriver.exe");
 d = new ChromeDriver();

Comment: @as1andrey1 вы инициализировали `d`, а используете `driver` как так?

Comment: Нет, это опечатка , я использую только Webdriver d

Answer (score 0, accepted):

нужно установить Google Chrome версии 49.0.2623.112